# Custom citation text

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I like the `alphabetical` type of style of citing works (e.g., having [ABC21] appear instead of [1]). However, sometimes I want to customise the appearance instead of having the document automatically render it as [Abbreviated author name + year]. For example, I might want a citation of *Higher algebra* to appear as [HA] instead of [Lur17] because with such a well-known title I feel it conveys more clearly what is being cited.

Is there a good way to accomplish this? I'm using `biblatex`, and I would like something that doesn't require a different way of citing the entry. I tried to find something in the biblatex documentation, but I found it quite opaque and hard to get through for someone who barely knows the basics of how to use it.

Concretely, what would I have to add to my entry in my `.bib`-file to accomplish this?

```
@unpublished{ha,
    author = {Jacob Lurie},
    title = {Higher algebra},
    year = {2017},
    month = {09},
    note = {Unpublished. Available online at \url{https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/}}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case someone stumbles upon this question like me, add in the entry the line

```
shorthand={HA}
```